# Is there any way to hide the part of the element that is under another?

Tags: css

[image]

In the image it can be seen that when I make a hovering effect the green box is seen below. 
when I hovering on the yellow box I do not want to see the green part that intersects and that can be seen by the opacity
Is there any way to cut the intersected part or not show it?

this is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="son">
    This is a title, while has hovering, I dont should see the green square under
  </div>
</div>

.container{
  height: 507px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(168,207,69,1);
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top:50px;
  z-index:1;
}
.son:hover{

  background-color: rgba(255,207,69,0.5);

}
.son{
  z-index:2;
  position:relative;
  top:-20px;
  width: 300px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: rgba(255,207,69,1);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7zm8ascx/

Answer (score 3):

Just use 100% opacity in your `.son:hover` `background-color`. That'll cover the green rectangle. (Obviously, you'll need to change the color values to get the same color you had with 50% opacity.)

```css
.container {
  background-color: rgba(168,207,69,1);
  border-radius: 32px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 500px;
}
.son:hover {
  background-color: rgba(254,230,166,1);
}
.son {
  background-color: rgba(255,207,69,1);
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="son">
    This is a title, while has hovering, I dont should see the green square under
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this will be using opaque color (`rgba(255, 231, 161,1)` in your case).

If you don't need opacity, just don't use `rgba` and use `rgb` or HEX colors.

Answer (score 0):

just update this code

```
.son:hover {
  background-color: #FFE7A2;
}
```